# How to apply sort by based on sum while join three table in Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, join

I have one scenario, I need to implement in linq query.

Scenario:

`Product` table:

```
| Id  | Name |
| --- | ---- |
| 1   | ABC  |
| 2   | MNO  |
| 3   | FGH  |
| 4   | YUI  |
| 5   | IOP  |
| 6   | RTY  |
```

New Rate table:

```
| ID | Rate |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | 89   |
| 1  |  4   |
| 1  | 23   |
| 2  | 54   |
| 3  | 93   |
| 3  | 40   |
| 4  | 55   |
| 4  | 34   |
| 5  | 32   |
| 5  | 67   |
| 5  | 89   |
| 5  | 78   |
```

Old Rate table:

```
| ID | Rate |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | 90   |
| 2  | 78   |
| 2  | 67   |
| 3  | 70   |
| 5  | 78   |
| 6  | 20   |
```

Result with sum of sorting:

```
| ID | Rate |
| -- | ---- |
| 5  | 344  |
| 1  | 206  |
| 3  | 203  |
| 2  | 199  |
| 4  | 89   |
| 6  | 20   |
```

I need to join the `New Rate Table` and `Old Rate Table` tables based on Id and apply sorting for total sum.

Please suggest any approach in Linq in C#

I tried this code, but it's not working:

```
Details = (from ld in Details.AsQueryable()                                                                     
           join cr in Context.RateDetails on ld.Id equals cr.Id                                                  
           into cRate from x in cRate.DefaultIfEmpty(new RateDetail())                                                      
           join cs in Context.Accessorials on ld.Id equals cs.Id                                                
           into cSRate from y in cSRate.DefaultIfEmpty(new AccessorialRead())                                   
           orderby new { totalRate = x.TotalRate + y.RateAmount } descending                                    
           select ld).ToList()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Do you want to `JOIN` them or `UNION` them? Also, how do the table names in your LINQ query map to the table names in the table diagram? Finally, what does `.AsNoTracking()` do?

Comment: Ignore the question about .AsNoTracking(). Duh. It's EF.

Comment: Hi @Mike Hofer, I want to 'JOIN' them and Please Ignore the '.AsNoTracking()' it's related to EF.